# Anonymously access SharePoint 2013 List using REST API with Default Credentials C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, rest

I want to get List from Sharepoint using mobile devices therefore I am using REST API with DefaultCredentials,I have already given Read rights to my List but I am getting

`The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`

My Code Is:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("ListUrl");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Is it possible via REST API or any other solution??
Is there anything that I am missing???

Comment: Where are you using this? Console application / app?

Comment: I want to access it via mobile app means outside the SharePoint. I was to get SharePoint List anonymously.